# cloudflare-sdk : Can not Add MX record via API

Tags: php, dns, cloudflare, mx-record

I can not add the MX record in a Zone from the API. I’m using PHP sdk with this statement

```
$dns->addRecord(‘a07e52c68721e…’, ‘MX’, ‘@’, ‘mxa.mailgun.org’, 0, false, ‘10’)
```

And as a result (incomplete by the way)

```
GuzzleHttp/Exception/ClientException with message 'Client error: `POST https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/a07e52c68721e.../dns_records` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"success":false,"errors":[{"code":1004,"message":"DNS Validation Error","error_chain":[{"code":9104,"message":"priority  (truncated...)
```

**I already read [Issue 41](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-php/issues/41) and I use cloudflare-php 1.1.0**

Any help is welcome

Comment: What is error code 1004 in Cloudflare API documentation? Do you really have `…` in your label? Are you sure the last parameter must be a string? And that `false` is recognized?

Comment: Yes... signature of this function is  `public function addRecord( string $zoneID, string $type, string $name,  string $content,   int $ttl = 0, bool $proxied = true, string $priority = '' ): bool`

Comment: Probably not related but TTL 0 is not a good idea...

Comment: I don't think because there is https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-php/blob/master/src/Endpoints/DNS.php#L50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was obviously due to the argument `ttd` which had as default value 0 ... I put exactly 0 while the appropriate argument should be between 120 and 2147483647 according to the [official documentation](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-create-dns-record).
So, it's this code that worked as @Patrick Mevzek

```
$dns->addRecord(‘a07e52c68721e…’, ‘MX’, ‘@’, ‘mxa.mailgun.org’, 120, false, ‘10’)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem! I had this error and solved it by upgrading the SDK version from 1.1 to 1.1.2 in composer.json. This fixed the problem immediately! :)